# How to search using regex in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement search filter and I have array:

```
Var aa = ["Sage","Salsify (usually Purple Salsify or Oyster Plant)"];

var regex = RegExp("[a-zA-Z]?");
var wordList = vegetables.filter((elem, index)=>{
    return regex.test(elem);
})
```

I think this will match only characters but how to get full string `"Salsify (usually Purple Salsify or Oyster Plant)"` when user type `Salsify`?

Comment: What is your input string?

Answer (score 2):

For a simplistic filter, you could use [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
var aa = ["Sage","Salsify (usually Purple Salsify or Oyster Plant)"];
var query = 'salsify';

var wordList = aa.filter((elem, index)=> elem.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));
console.log(wordList);
```

To use a regular expression, your RegExp would need to be built dynamically based on the search query:

```js
var aa = ["Sage","Salsify (usually Purple Salsify or Oyster Plant)"];
var query = 'salsify';

var expr = new RegExp(query, "gi");

var wordList = aa.filter((elem, index)=> expr.test(elem));
console.log(wordList);
```

Comment: the key here... is that if query comes from user input, then both query and the values in the array have to be normalized... so using something like String.toLowerCase() is critical... otherwise case mismatch will cause regex, or .includes() to not match.   Good call

Comment: @DynasticSponge yep that is why I included the `i` flag in the `RegExp` which means case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
aa.filter((e) => /.*Salsify.*/.test(e))
```

You'll get every element of `aa` in which the string `Salsify` appears.